# How to break array into string with double quotes

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to get an array to a string with double quotes for each:

```
$array = ["a", "b", "c"]

implode(', ', $array) // => "a, b, c"
```

Not what I want, expected string to look like: `"a", "b", "c"`

I want to use the `$array` in a string so having "Notice" errors. Possible and how?

My actual string looks like: `"name: ['. $array . ']"`

Comment: what's the opposite of `implode`?

Comment: What's the purpose of this, seems like json `{name:["a","b","c"]`, if so it's better to do it this way 'json_encode( ["name" => $array]);` just sating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you say break and array yet you use implode.  So I will show you how to do this with implode.

```
 $array = ["a", "b", "c"];
 $str = '"'.implode( '","', $array).'"';
 echo $str;
```

This should give you

```
     "a", "b", "c"
```

because you are adding the leading and trailing quotes now, and a quote before and after the comma.  Simple really.

What's the purpose of this, seems like json `{` `name:["a","b","c"]` `}`, if so it's better to do it this way

```
     $str = json_encode( ["name" => $array]);
```

just saying.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the items in the string try the using the following implode 'glue':

```
<?php

$array = ["a", "b", "c"];

//Quote as much as we can
$string = implode('", "', $array); //a", "b", "c

//Quote ends of string
$string = '"'.$string.'"'; //"a", "b", "c"

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: beat you to it. by half a minute :-p

Comment: i saw it flash i was typing.. had to finish haha! Pretty much the same solution though which is always nice!

Comment: yea the question was a bit confusing, I think of breaking something as explode,  seems more violent now that I type it.  LOL